# Is there a way to push new files to a github enterprise repo automatically?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, airflow, cloud, github-api

I have a utility, that runs as a Airflow DAG, that creates dynamic code based on the user input. The code it creates is a python file.

Basically, once the Utility DAG run is over as new .py file is created.

I want to auto commit this new python file to an existing repo. How can I do it from within the Utility?

One thing I am think of is GitHub API token. Or may be there is some other better way to do so. The problem here is the Utility DAG on Airflow runs using a Google Service account, and that SA does not have a GitHub account. I was thinking to use my token to push the newly generated files to the respective repo.

Any guidance on this will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is SSH an option?

Comment: Hi @JimRedmond, it can be an option. I use SSH to clone, commit etc. from my account, but I have not done so using some SA. Is there a way to do so? It will be great if you can share some insight.

Comment: I'm not sure about Airflow's capabilities, but if you can securely give it a private key (perhaps as an environment variable) then you can add the matching public key to that GitHub repo as a deploy key (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys).